# How to increase the max connections in Postgres 12?

Tags: postgresql

What parameters and how should be changed in postgresql.conf to increase the maximum number of connections to 3000 if the RAM is 60GB?

Comment: Don't increase the limit to 3000.

Answer (score 1):

To increase connection, you should change `max_connections`

But I suggest you use the website https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/, This website help you config Postgres server

---

PS:

in my opinion, don't increase connection to 3000 because if you increase connection, database work memory decreased for each client, you can use [pgbouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/)

Pgbouncer is the proxy and connection manager when you have too many clients to connecting to the database, this proxy handle clients and create a pool connection

Comment: Thanks. What would be the maximum connection for a 60GB machine? What performance should my machine have to support 3000 connections? How do I find the optimum?

Comment: As far as one can tell, It is a better set of a maximum connection between 100 and 400, But if you need to set it to 3000 or more than connections you should monitor your memory performance, and if need more memory you have to increase memory because the connection number relative with memory. It is better to use pool connection in application